# Addthis Ajax and Share-Tracking via Profile-ID

Tags: javascript, ajax, addthis

I've struggled with this problem for quite a while now and have not figured it out yet. 
I am loading addThis via javascript, like in [this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dularion/WWngg/6/)

And The Profile ID doesnt work, the shares I make do not get tracked. The easiest way to test if it is connected to the Profile or not (without loggin in to addthis) is to share via email and see if the email template works. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dularion/Fxnt8/3/) with a working email template (to compare)

I read [here](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/240144-email-template-when-using-ajax-bug-?t=89322) that this little part var addthis_config = { pubid: 'YOUR-ID'}; makes it work, and as you can see in the first fiddle, I included that variable. But it still won't work. What do I need to do to make this work?

I appreciate every help you guys can offer!